# Es aggregation query is slow. How to improve?

Tags: elasticsearch, cluster-computing, nodes

We have **7552642** documents with total size of 94.290219647 gibabyte data at elasticsearch production cluster.

#### XMS and XMX:

> /usr/bin/java -Xms20g -Xmx20g

### Cluster Information:

```
{
"cluster_name": "production",
"status": "green",
"timed_out": false,
"number_of_nodes": 2,
"number_of_data_nodes": 2,
"active_primary_shards": 10,
"active_shards": 20,
"relocating_shards": 0,
"initializing_shards": 0,
"unassigned_shards": 0,
"delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
"number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
"number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
"active_shards_percent_as_number": 100
}
```

### Mapping

```
"posts": {
    "mappings": {
        "information": {
            "_all": {
                "enabled": true
            },
            "properties":{
                "post_created_time": {
                    "type": "date"
                },
                "post_impressions": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "post_interactions": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "post_media_value": {
                    "type": "float"
                },
                "post_message": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "post_reach": {
                    "type": "double"
                },
                "post_type": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "profile_id": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "profile_name": {
                    "type": "text"
                },
                "platform_followed_by" :{
                     "type: "long"
                 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Aggregation query:

```
{  
"size":0,
"aggs":{  
    "total_influencers":{  
        "cardinality":{  
            "field":"profile_id"
        }
    },
    "profiles_reach_bucket":{  
        "terms":{  
            "size":2147483639,
            "field":"profile_id"
        },
        "aggs":{  
            "media_reach_bucket":{  
                "terms":{  
                    "field":"_type",
                    "size":2147483639
                },
                "aggs":{  
                    "media_reach":{  
                        "avg":{  
                            "field":"post_reach"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "total_media_reach":{  
                "sum_bucket":{  
                    "buckets_path":"media_reach_bucket>media_reach"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "total_reach":{  
        "sum_bucket":{  
            "buckets_path":"profiles_reach_bucket>total_media_reach"
        }
    },
    "total_impressions":{  
        "sum":{  
            "field":"post_impressions"
        }
    },
    "total_interactions":{  
        "sum":{  
            "field":"post_interactions"
        }
    },
    "total_followers":{  
        "sum":{  
            "field":"platform_followed_by"
        }
    },
    "interactions_for_media_value":{  
        "terms":{  
            "size":2147483639,
            "field":"_type"
        },
        "aggs":{  
            "interaction":{  
                "sum":{  
                    "field":"post_interactions"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "impressions_for_media_value":{  
        "terms":{  
            "size":2147483639,
            "field":"_type"
        },
        "aggs":{  
            "impression":{  
                "sum":{  
                    "field":"post_impressions"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"query":{  
    "bool":{  
        "must":[  
            {  
                "query_string":{  
                    "query":"post_message:*food* post_description:*food* post_title:*food* "
                }
            }
        ],
        "filter":[  
            {  
                "range":{  
                    "post_created_time":{  
                        "gte":1533427200,
                        "lte":1549324800
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
      }
   }
}
```

### Result:

The above query took

```
"took": 6685,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 10,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
}
```

Any suggestion to optimize will be grateful.

Comment: XMX, XMS, available off heap space? Aggregations time measure after warm up?

Comment: -Xms20g -Xmx20g

Comment: And how much RAM you have per node?

Comment: with "size":2147483639 it seems you are trying to get your metrics for all influencers at once. Such an aggregation in a 90GB index in 6sec don't seems to be really slow. Retrieving all the metrics at once is really what you need?

Comment: There can be a lot of things to consider such as, (1) There are 10 shards in index. Can you use routing during index-time and then in search time to target only one shard while querying. This depends on if documents can be grouped on some common  property and that group of docs are targeted to one shard. (2) Can you reduce the level of aggs. Deeper the nestings of aggregation slower it will be. (3) Wildcards in query are heavy in themselves and using them on both side of term (*food*) is heavier. Alternate can be ngram analyzer or its variants, whitespace analyzer etc.

Comment: @Mysterion Node 1 - 20GB, Node 2 - 8GB

Comment: @PierreMallet We need realtime metrics

Comment: @NishantSaini Thanks for the suggestion, I will work on it.

Comment: You clearly have not enough RAM to run those things efficient enoug